# Iterate over Array and add element to empty dictionary in Swift 2.2

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, dictionary

I have an array of colors but the number of elements in the array can change. For example I may have 1 color 1 day but 3 colors the next day. How can I iterate over the array and then add the elements to an empty dictionary?

```
var colors = [String]()
var colorDict = [String: AnyObject]()

//day1 the array has 2 colors
self.colors = ["red", "blue"]

//day2 the array has 3 colors
self.colors = ["red", "blue", "orange"]

//day3 the array has 1 color
self.colors = ["blue"]

//regardless of which day it is I need to iterate over the array and add whatever is inside to the dictionary
for color in self.colors{
//how would I add elements to self.colorDict?
}
```

Comment: Why you want use `Dictionary`? what values will it hold for color keys? Maybe better to use `Set`, if you wish hold colors that used at least one time?

Comment: Dictionary requires key and value for each entry. You cannot add just one thing to a dictionary; you need a key _and_ a value. You have just values (or just keys). The question makes no sense. Show an example of your desired output (the resulting dictionary). What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Matt I understand your point. Your right it's not clear. I was;t trying to get over complicated but I have a collectionView. User's can upload any number of color names. I take those colors names and add them to an empty array (colorDict). Some users may upload 1 color and other 4 colors etc. Once the colors are added to the array I need to iterate over it and add the color names to Firebase. The color names are actually the values. The key names can be anything. The reason I'm using a dictionary is because Firebase works with key/value pairs.

Comment: But wouldn't it  make copies of same colors in your DB...And the moment you call `self.colors = ["red", "blue", "orange"]` the values of `self.colors = ["red", "blue"]` will be replaced not appended..

Comment: The key/values would only be added to each individual user. So if Jill uploaded 1 color then on her FB path she would only have 1 key/value pair. If Jack uploaded 3 colors then on his FB path he would only have 3 key/value pairs. Jack's 3 colors would have no effect on Jill''s 1 color. There's a lot of code between the collectionView code and Firebase code. I was trying to keep things simple. Uploading all the code would've probably been more clear. Although Oleg's answer is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving of the issue try to use this approach:

```
for color in colors{
    colorDict["someKey"] = color
}
```

As you can see you should firstly assign some key and than value for that key.

In my case key is "someKey" and value color from array.

If you do not have clear amount of keys. Enumerate with index of the array item.

```
for (index, element) in colors.enumerate() {
     colorDict[String(index)] = element
}
```

Comment: this is the same as just doing `colorDict["someKey"] = colors.last`

Comment: yes you are right. I just show that all he need is to set key. If he would like to obtain more than 1 element he should use different keys.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, I should've been more clear with the code. But in a nutshell the color names are the values. The problem I'm having is since the amount of color names can vary, what I'm lost with is I can't have a predetermined amount of key names because I don't know how many values will be added. For example if I had 3 key names but a user added 5 color names there'd be a crash.

Comment: @labnxx, you could work backwords, treat your object as the key, and your key as the object,  then if the object is not found as a key, add it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, you lost me. Can you write a short example?

Comment: @labnxx, you question is confusing,  maybe if you cleaned it up I will provide an answer.  Oleg, the enumerator would cause problems  I would think, since colors is an array, not a dictionary

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, thanks for the help. I'm looking over what you added. Ahhhhh I think I get it. You cast the index number as a string and the becomes the key to the color value which is the element -correct?

Comment: @ Knight0fDragon, sorry, I now realize my code and question isn't as straight forward as I expected. I appreciate your help. Here's some clarity. I was't trying to get over complicated but I have a collectionView. User's can upload any number of color names. I take those colors names and add them to an empty array (colorDict). Some users may upload 1 color and others 4 colors etc. Once the colors are added to the array I need to iterate over it and add the color names to Firebase. The color names are actually the values. The key names can be anything.  Firebase works with key/value pairs

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, 1 last question if you don't mind. How do I access each new key/value pair inside the new colorDict?

Comment: @labnxx by the key. Some dictionary var dict =  [key1: blue, key2: red]. Use key to fetch value like dict["key1"]

Comment: Ahhhhh I forgot about that. The basics!! Thank you very much my friend!!! I'm good now :)